# Unproxy object in JPA without specific API for Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate as JPA provider. I read about Proxy objects in Hibernate and found problem in my `equals()` method for `User` entity:

```java
@Entity
class User {

    private String username;
    private String email;

    // other fields, getters, setters, etc.

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return username.equals(user.username) && email.equals(user.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(username, email);
    }
}
```

In that `equals()` implementation I have Proxy `User` object and every time when I try check `user.username` or `user.email` it's `null`. Do I understand problem correctly?

So I found that implementation with [`unproxy()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#unproxy-java.lang.Object-) method as solution of my problem:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
    User user = (User) o;
    if (o instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        user = (User) Hibernate.unproxy(o);
    }
    return username.equals(user.username) && email.equals(user.email);
}
```

But I don't know if this is the correct method. I heard that it is worth using implementations coming directly from `javax.persistence` instead of Hibernate to become independent from JPA provider.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. There's definitely something wrong somewhere else. What's the code that's failing because of the equals? And could you show the entity full mapping?

Comment: Use getters and your problem goes away. The proxy is a subclass and delegates to the original entity. There’s no need to unproxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **getters** inside your equals/hashcode methods, this way it will access (or load from db) the actual values.